# Subquery select where clause

Tags: django

I have this sql statement:

```
SELECT * FROM result WHERE bet_id IN (SELECT id FROM bet WHERE STATUS="Active")
```

and this is my view:

```
def manageresult(request):
    if 'usid' in request.session:
        result = Result.objects.all()
        admin = Admin.objects.get(id=request.session['usid'])
        return render(request, 'manageresult.html', {'result':result,'admin':admin})
    else:
        return redirect('login')
```

How to change `result = Result.objects.all()` to that sql statement?
This is bet model:

```
class Bet(models.Model):
    status = models.CharField(max_length=20, default="Active")
```

This is Result model:

```
class Result(models.Model):
    bet = models.OneToOneField(Bet, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: Could you show your models and relevant model fields?

Comment: @Sayse i've add the model in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*disclaimer: when writing this answer, the models in question were not known*

In case the `Result` model has a `ForeignKey` to `Bet`, you can filter by joins - it would make it more like

`result = Result.objects.filter(bet__status='Active')`

which would translate to the below SQL query

`SELECT result.* FROM result INNER JOIN bet on result.bet_id = bet.id WHERE bet.STATUS="Active"`

See Django's documentation on [Lookups that span relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships)

If that is not the case, [Todor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2062318/todor)'s answer is the way to go

Answer (score 2):

You can use `bet__status=...`:

```
result = Result.objects.filter(bet__status='Active')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make querysets nested

```
result = Result.objects.filter(bet__in=Bet.objects.filter(status='active'))
```